# Consume a single generator by multiple filtered generators

Tags: python, generator

I have a file that contain records which look like this:

```
>uniqueid#BARCODE1
content content
content content
>uniqueid#BARCODE2
content content
content content
>uniqueid#BARCODE1
content content
content content
...
```

There are ~10 million records with ~300 unique barcodes, and the order of barcodes is random. My goal is to split the file into 300 files. I'd like to do this passing through the file only once with a generator that yields records.

I have solved this problem in the past by reading through the file many times, or by loading the entire file into memory. I'd like to solve the problem using a generator approach to keep memory usage down and to only read through the file once.

**Is it possible to instantiate 300 generators and have some logic that dispatches the records to the correct generator?** Then I could simply write out the contents of each generator to a file. Would I need to then have handles open to all 300 files I want to write at once?

Comment: what is your desired output? how files should be called?

Comment: is it a sample from real file or some pseudo data?

Comment: Yes, it's possible—there may even be a better way to do what you want. Please edit your question and add some sample code and more realistic sample input file data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be done with generators, but we don't need 300 of them, just 1 is enough.

As far as i understand `'uniqueid#BARCODE1'` barcode consist of two parts:

- `'>uniqueid#'` prefix,
- `'BARCODE1'` barcode itself.

so let's start with writing simple checker

```
BAR_CODE_PREFIX = '>uniqueid#'


def is_bar_code(text):
    return text.startswith(BAR_CODE_PREFIX)
```

then for parsing barcodes contents we can write generator

```
def parse_content(lines):
    lines_iterator = iter(lines)
    # we assume that the first line is a barcode
    bar_code = next(lines_iterator)
    contents = []
    for line in lines_iterator:
        if is_bar_code(line):
            # next barcode is found
            yield bar_code, contents
            bar_code = line
            contents = []
        else:
            contents.append(line)
    # to yield last barcode with its contents
    yield bar_code, contents
```

then assuming you want to name files after barcodes we can write

```
def split_src(src_path):
    with open(src_path) as src_file:
        for bar_code, content_lines in parse_content(src_file):
            bar_code_index = bar_code[len(BAR_CODE_PREFIX):].rstrip('\n')
            # we use `append` mode
            # because in the different parts of file 
            # there are contents of the same barcode
            with open(bar_code_index, mode='a') as dst_file:
                dst_file.writelines(content_lines)
```

which walks exactly one time through whole file.

## Test

Let's create `src.txt` file which consist of

```
>uniqueid#BARCODE1
content11
>uniqueid#BARCODE2
content21
>uniqueid#BARCODE1
content12
content12
>uniqueid#BARCODE3
content31
>uniqueid#BARCODE2
content22
```

then after calling

```
split_src('src.txt')
```

there will be created next files:

- `BARCODE1` with lines

  ```
  content11
  content12
  content12
  ```
- `BARCODE2` with lines

  ```
  content21
  content22
  ```
- `BARCODE3` with lines

  ```
  content31
  ```

Comment: I wasn't clear in the question, but I'd like to avoid opening and closing files 10 million times. This answer does meet the criteria of the question the way i posed it though.

Comment: @elsherbini: you can update question with more details